# How to edit a string from a form in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a form that submits some data to a database `Databse::create($input);`. I want to edit the `input` variable that contains a string with the submitted data from the form content.

I need to make this happen in the `controller`.

```
public function store()
{
    $input = Request::all();
    Databse::create($input);
}
```

Comment: can you please so us some of your codes ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to save the input in a variable and then you can make whatever you want with that variable. Of course you can make that in your controller

```
$variableToEdit = $request->input('theInputToBeEdit');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Request` class in your controller method and bind it with `$request` service container. Your current request will be automatically injected by the service container. Now you can change the data from the service container and store it in database. Your controller should look like this:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request['field_name'] = 'your data';
    $input = $request->all(); //you can skip this line and
    Databse::create($input); // use '$request->all()' instead of '$input'
}
```